# Italics for many phrases in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been working on a code that finds and replaces words to make them italics. However, I cannot figure out how to make this more efficient using an array. 
Currently my code is this were I just keep copying and pasting the with loop:

```
    Sub ItalicsText()
'
' ItalicsText Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Lord of the Rings"
        .Replacement.Text = "Lord of the Rings"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.EscapeKey
End Sub
```

However, I would like to make it so that I could have an array like:

```
vFindText = Array("Lord of the Rings", "blah", "blah")
```

I want to do this because I have hundreds of phrases to check and want to make it faster for me to code.

Comment: Can you search like that using the Word Find dialog? If not, you can't do it in a call to `Find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub AllTexts()
    Dim vFindText, v
    vFindText = Array("Lord of the Rings", "blah", "blah")
    For Each v in vFindText 
        ItalicsText v
    Next v
End Sub


Sub ItalicsText(findWhat)

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findWhat
        .Replacement.Text = findWhat
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.EscapeKey
End Sub
```